# CreateWindowEx failing with error 1407 even though registration was successful?

Tags: c++, winapi

i've been experimenting with wrapping some basic win32 functionality in classes while i work with d3d, and am stumped for why the CreateWindowEx function fails saying a class doesn't exist AFTER i create a valid class with RegisterClassEx, no errors to speak of :\ . I get the feeling i'm missing some silly little thing, but i can't find it. Here is some of the code:

I have a class that extends WNDCLASSEX like this, so that it has a normal std::string for a class name and a simplified constructor:

```
#ifndef WINDOWCLASS_H
#define WINDOWCLASS_H

#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include "WindowAbstract.h"
using namespace std;

class WindowClass : public WNDCLASSEX
{
public:
    WindowClass(string className, WindowAbstract * window);
    ~WindowClass();

    bool Register();
    string ClassName() {return m_className;}

    friend class WindowAbstract;

private:
    string m_className;
};

#endif
```

And here is the constructor for the class:

```
WindowClass::WindowClass(string className, WindowAbstract * window)
{

    cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    style         = 0;
    lpfnWndProc   = window->WndProc;
    cbClsExtra    = 0;
    cbWndExtra    = 0;
    hInstance     = hInstance;
    hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    lpszMenuName  = NULL;
    lpszClassName = className.c_str();
    hIconSm       = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

    m_className = className;
}
```

here is the register function to be called after it's constructed:

```
bool WindowClass::Register()
{
    if(RegisterClassEx(this) == 0)
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

The WindowAbstract class contains the window procedure and is created first, to pass the pointer to it's function to the WindowClass object.

```
#ifndef WINDOWABSTRACT_H
#define WINDOWABSTRACT_H

#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class WindowAbstract
{

public:
    WindowAbstract();
    ~WindowAbstract();

    bool Create(string windowTitle, string className, DWORD styles, DWORD extendedStyles, int top, int left, int bot, int right, HWND parent, HMENU id);
    void Show();

    friend class WindowClass;

private:
    static LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
    HWND m_hwnd;

};

#endif
```

And here is the create function:

```
bool WindowAbstract::Create(string windowTitle, string className, DWORD styles, DWORD extendedStyles, int top, int left, int bot, int right, HWND parent, HMENU id)
{
    m_hwnd = CreateWindowEx(extendedStyles, className.c_str() , windowTitle.c_str(), styles, top, left, bot, right, parent, id, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
    if(!m_hwnd)
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

so after seeing all that, here is the actual winmain where i test it out:

```
#include "WindowAbstract.h"
#include "WindowClass.h"


int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    DWORD error;
    bool result;
    char buffer[100];

    WindowAbstract * window = new WindowAbstract();
    WindowClass * myClass = new WindowClass("myClass", window);

    result = myClass->Register();
    if(!result)
    {
        error = GetLastError();
        sprintf_s(buffer, "error: %i", error);
        MessageBox(NULL, buffer, "Registration Failed!", MB_OK);
    }

    result = window->Create("my Window", myClass->ClassName(), WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, 20, 20, 200, 200, NULL, NULL);
    if(!result)
    {
        error = GetLastError();
        sprintf_s(buffer, "error: %i", error);
        MessageBox(NULL, buffer, "Window Creation Failed!", MB_OK);

    }

    window->Show();

    MSG msg;
    while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    if(window)
    {
        delete window;
        window = 0;
    }

    if(myClass)
    {
        delete myClass;
        myClass = 0;
    }

    return msg.wParam;
}
```

so, in conclusion, this is so confusing because the Register function of the WindowClass object returns fine, but the create function fails in the WindowAbstract object because there is no valid class,(error 1407), with that name? Whuh?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is `lpszClassName = className.c_str()` in the `WindowClass` constructor.  In general, you shouldn't rely on the value returned from `c_str()` being available for any length of time.

In this case, you're (effectively) taking the address of a local variable which may have ceased to exist by the time you call `RegisterClassEx`.  So `RegisterClassEx` is succeeding, but who knows what name it is seeing?

`lpszClassName = m_className.c_str()` would probably work (if you assigned `m_className` first) but it's still sketchy.  Better to call `c_str()` immediately before you call `RegisterClassEx`.

Comment: ahhh, that did it :P. When i called the c_str() function within the constructor, i assume that member was only correctly valid for as long as it was in the constructors scope, so when the constructor ended and i call the Register member, it was incorrect. Now i did away with the Register member entirely and just called RegisterClassEx at the end of the constructor, and my window was created fine (YAY!) . Thanks for your suggestion! :P

Comment: I actually took your advice, assigned the passed in string to the m_className member like before, omitting the lpszClassName = className.c_str(); statement in the constructor, and then putting lpszClassName = m_className.c_str(); right before i registered the class in the Register member. and that worked like a charm, so now i can still check for RegisterClassEx failing.  WOOT :P . So in conclusion i have now learned that the char * returned by string::c_str() is local and only valid for the current scope.

Comment: The `char *` returned by `string::c_str()` is valid [only until the next non-const method call on the string (or the string is destructed)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/).

Answer (score 3):

It is not clear what the line

```
hInstance     = hInstance;
```

is intended to accomplish. In reality, what it does is initialize hInstance with itself, so it is effectively uninitialized. That uninitialized value is probably not the same value passed to CreateWindowEx.

Comment: ah, this was actually an accident, because at one point hInstance was a parameter being passed into the function, and i was originally just making a class that contained a WNDCLASSEX member. now i should replace that with hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);

Thanks for the catch, but that didn't solve my initial problem :\

Comment: Use the instance handle of the actual module. [Using `GetModuleHandle(NULL)` is like identity theft](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/07/15/10186685.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

I faced a similar error with the CreateWindowEx function but it was due to having forgotten to InitCommonControls. Once I did that everything went honky-dory.

Comment: If `InitCommonControls()` fixed the issue then, clearly, you weren't attempting to instantiate a window class you registered. This is an answer to a different question.