# API or configuration that verifies internal Windows data structures

Tags: windows, winapi, memory-leaks, crash

I need to find a memory corruption bug that affects Windows API. Basically, after running the program for some time, the `CreateWindowEx` function returns a `NULL` handle and `GetLastError()` returns 1407, which means "Cannot find window class". I've checked the `lpClassName` parameter and it's OK, and the class was already registered. In fact, the program creates many windows of that class normally, then suddenly `CreateWindowEx` refuses to create a new window and gives error 1407. There is only one thread on this program, and we are sure there's no call to `UnregisterClass` after the problem window class was registered.

We suspect that our program is corrupting some `USER32` or other Windows data structure. But running it with [Application Verifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms220948%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and [Visual Leak Detector for Visual C++](http://vld.codeplex.com/), no leak or memory corruption was found. Resource usage is also low, the number of Window handles never gets greater than 2k and committed memory never gets greater than 50mb.

This brings me to the title of this question: Is there some Windows API, or Windows configuration option than can check, either on demand or continuously, the state of Windows data structures of a given process? I'm already using Application Verifier with many enabled checks, but it simply doesn't catch any error.

Comment: Try [Deleaker](http://www.deleaker.com/download.html).

Comment: Also check the HINSTANCE. Does the window procedure receive WM_NCCREATE?

Comment: @RaymondChen HINSTANCE is correct. The window procedure doesn't run for the problematic CreateWindowEx.

Comment: Add a call to GetClassInfo for debugging purposes. Does GetClassInfo succeed? Class information is not stored on the application space so it would be hard for you to corrupt it. Maybe somebody else (outside your code) is unregistering it by mistake. I hope you're using the HINSTANCE of your DLL rather than GetModuleHandle(0).

Comment: could be an xy problem... it seems pretty unlikely that you would be able to trash windows memory without generating an exception?  and also to do it in such a way that you would be able to reliably create this issue?  maybe you should post some code.  your diagnosis may be wrong.  for example, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9152280/createwindowex-failing-with-error-1407-even-though-registration-was-successful.  you most certainly don't have the same issue, but that is just to give you an idea that other problems can happen other than what you suspect...

Comment: Thanks, @RaymondChen. GetClassInfo() succeed with the same lpClassName just after the failed call to CreateWindowEx. The WNDCLASS seems to be correct. The member lpszClassName points to correct class name, and member lpfnWndProc points to correct window procedure.

Comment: Thanks, @thang. The program uses a huge framework, with spread API calls. I've tried to isolate the bug on a small program, but I was not able to reproduce the bug. The strange thing about this bug is that many previous calls to CreateWindowEx for a given window class succeed, then suddenly a call fails. That's why I suspect is a memory corruption bug.

Comment: The last thing I can think of is that somebody installed a hook that is rejecting the window creation. To find out for sure, you'll have to connect a kernel debugger and trace the window creation through win32k. (Not fun.)

Comment: I made a hack where I perform a new call to CreateWindowEx just after the failed call, with exact same parameters. For my surprise, the second call is successful! Perhaps this is related to some timing issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a hack where I perform a new call to CreateWindowEx just after the failed call, with exact same parameters. For my surprise, the second call is successful! Perhaps this is related to some timing issue.